# Scala Source.fromReader() is missing?

Tags: scala, resultset, reader

I'm trying to process a CLOB value from a database using `ResultSet.getCharacterStream()` which results in a `java.io.Reader`.

Why is there no `Source.fromReader()` method?

Answer (score 1):

That's because `java.io.Reader` and `scala.io.Source` have somewhat similar / intersecting responsibilities. You can use one or the other, but it doesn't make any sense to stack them on top of each other and use both simultaneously.

Try using

```
Source.fromInputStream(resultSet.getBinaryStream, yourClobEncoding)
```

instead.